# need to change obj structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures

I have the following output from the DB:

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "lineItem": "PC COST",
        "lineItemAmount": 1000,
        "fiscalYear": 2022,
        "routing_Tool_Id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "lineItem": "PC COST",
        "lineItemAmount": 100,
        "fiscalYear": 2023,
        "routing_Tool_Id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "lineItem": "Travel",
        "lineItemAmount": 10,
        "fiscalYear": 2024,
        "routing_Tool_Id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "lineItem": "Travel",
        "lineItemAmount": 100,
        "fiscalYear": 2026,
        "routing_Tool_Id": 1
    }
]
```

However, it needs to be converted it in the following form -each FY has the value for the `lineAmount`

```
[
    {
        "LineItem": "PC COST",
        "currentFy": 1000,
        "currentFy01": 100,
        "currentFy02": null,
        "currentFy03": null,
        "currentFy04": null,
        "currentFy05": null
    },
    {
        "LineItem": "Travel",
        "currentFy": null,
        "currentFy01": null,
        "currentFy02": null,
        "currentFy03": 10,
        "currentFy04": null,
        "currentFy05": 100
    }
]
```

this is what I have so far- I have spent days looking for a clean way to do it.

```
const handleMatrix = (obj) => {
   
    let rowData = [];
    let index = [];

    // iterate obj and return unique line items
    function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
        return objectArray.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
            let key = obj[property]
            if (!acc[key]) {
                acc[key] = []
            }
            acc[key].push(obj)
            return acc
        }, {})
    }

    // assign unique line items to be used as main index for new obj
    index = groupBy(obj, 'lineItem');


    //console.log(index);

    Object.keys(index).map((lineItem) => (
        rowData.push({
            "LineItem": lineItem,
            "currentFy": null,
            "currentFy01": null,
            "currentFy02": null,
            "currentFy03": null,
            "currentFy04": null,
            "currentFy05": null,
        })
        )
    )

    
    // will update with current FY - function will be here updating array
    rowData[0]["currentFy"] = 2000
   
    return rowData 
}
```

Comment: Is your `I need it in the following form` the expected output for the input in the question?

Comment: Yes and rowData will get passed down to a function to render on a child component

Comment: Why doesn't the Travel with id 11 go into `"currentFy03": 10,`, and why does `"currentFy03": 10,` exist for the `PC_COST` section? Should those be reversed, or is there some logic I'm not getting?

Comment: You got it right. I fat-fingered data entry.  I fixed it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is `currentFy` dynamic? Eg, if I run the code next year, 2023 data goes into `currentFy`, 2024 into `currentFy01`, etc? How should older data be treated?

Comment: yes. it is in the DB is only saves the FY but on the front end, it does a calculation to display the current-FY + 5 years. Every year the current FY moves to the current one.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions at all

Comment: Any ints between " " were fat-fingered - I was building this as I got tired and reached for help. as I am stuck!.

Comment: Should values for the same line item and year be summed?

Comment: Phill, I do not understand your question. This function is to load data from the DB to render it.

Answer (score 2):

For each item:

- If an object for the LineItem doesn't exist yet, create it
- Calculate the FY difference and so the `lineItemAmount` can be assigned to the proper location

Finally, turn the object of objects into an array of objects.

```js
const input=[{id:6,lineItem:"PC COST",lineItemAmount:1e3,fiscalYear:2022,routing_Tool_Id:1},{id:10,lineItem:"PC COST",lineItemAmount:100,fiscalYear:2023,routing_Tool_Id:1},{id:11,lineItem:"Travel",lineItemAmount:10,fiscalYear:2024,routing_Tool_Id:1},{id:12,lineItem:"Travel",lineItemAmount:100,fiscalYear:2026,routing_Tool_Id:1}];

const initialFy = 2022;
const amountsByType = {};
const initialObj = {
  "currentFy": null,
  "currentFy01": null,
  "currentFy02": null,
  "currentFy03": null,
  "currentFy04": null,
  "currentFy05": null,
};
for (const { lineItem, lineItemAmount, fiscalYear } of input) {
  amountsByType[lineItem] ??= { LineItem: lineItem, ...initialObj };
  const fyDiff = fiscalYear - initialFy;
  if (fyDiff > 5 || fyDiff < 0) continue;
  const prop = 'currentFy' + (fyDiff === 0 ? '' : '0' + fyDiff);
  amountsByType[lineItem][prop] = lineItemAmount;
}
console.log(Object.values(amountsByType));
```

Comment: `??=`    didn't know JS had [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), nice

Comment: Dude, that works. You have no clue how many hours I have spent looking at this and not being able so to solve the Rubiks! Thank you!